# checkbox will not act normal

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="display:inline;  margin-left:30px;  ">  
                 <span class="checktext"><?php echo $newspec->spec;?><span>
                 <input class="postptext" style=" display:inline; float:right;" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $newspec->ID;?>" value="<?php echo $newspec->spec;?>">
</div>

<div style="display:inline;  margin-left:30px;  ">  
                 <span class="checktext"><?php echo $newspec->spec;?><span>
                 <input class="postptext" style=" display:inline; float:right;" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $newspec->ID;?>" value="<?php echo $newspec->spec;?>">
</div>

<div style="display:inline;  margin-left:30px;  ">  
                 <span class="checktext"><?php echo $newspec->spec;?><span>
                 <input class="postptext" style=" display:inline; float:right;" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $newspec->ID;?>" value="<?php echo $newspec->spec;?>">
</div>
```

This is css :

```
.postptext
{
   float:right;
}
```

This is my layout. This is what I see:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/D2K6KUW.png?1]

As you can see checkboxes are clearly floated right, yet they insist on acting weird. I cant set margin-left, margin-right , anything. They will just stay there. I put margin-left 30px to whole div, but only spans are applying the margin setting. I am confused. I know that some other css defines checkbox settings. But wouldnt float:Right be enough to override it? If not, what should I do to make them completely ignore the css which is defined by the template?

Comment: Post your rendered HTML, not the PHP which is irrelevant here.

Comment: How exactly do you want these checkboxes to look? Do you want them all in a line and floated to the right? Do you want them where the `span` element is to the left and the checkbox to the right?

Answer (score 0):

'yet they insist acting weird' is a little vague. Whithout knowing what is weird about it, it's hard to say how to make it not weird for that might be weird aswell.

Whenever I copy and test your code (while replacing php-code with some plain tekst) I get a different result, in which the checkboxes do float to the right (as they should I think).

However, my first guess for strange behaviour is because the divs are made inline. Because these are inline, the floated checkboxes will be floated relative to the body. At least, they did in my case when copying your code.

Making the divs inline-block, for example, has some effect in which the checkboxes are floated relative to the div.

A couple of remarks:

- input elements are already inline by default. Adding 'display:inline' to them seems to make little sense, unless there is other css that has affected the display in which case you have left out important some important information.
- adding 'float: right' to your checkboxes while the class postptext already provides float: right seems a little redundant to me.